# Expected number of tosses vs. likely number of tosses

Tags: probability

The question is:

> Suppose that a coin is biased such that the probability of obtaining a head is $0.6$. Find:
>
> a. the most likely number of tosses until a head is obtained
>
> b. the expected number of tosses until a head is obtained.

Now this is geometric distribution right so for the second part its $1/0.6$ which makes sense and I figured that out. But the answer for the first part is given as 1 which I cannot understand.

Comment: "Most likely" means highest probability. Do you know how to compute the probability that it takes $n$ tosses to get a head?

Comment: The probability that you need $n$ tosses to obtain a head is $P(X=n)= 0.4^{n-1}\cdot 0.6$